# When are data sets realized in Azure Data Factory data flows?

Tags: azure-data-factory

If I create a dataset with no schema, and then use it in a flow, where I have a `Select` schema modifier, when is the retrieval from the database done? Is it done on the full dataset including the complete schema and then the `select` projection is done or is it done in a just-in-time fashion, where the retrieval is done at the latest possible time in order to minimize the amount data retrieved?

Comment: Can't get your concern...what's the purpose of figuring this out?

Comment: Processing time on the database server and amount of data transferred. If the data is retrieved before the projection, much more data is retrieved, because all fields will be retrieved. If done using the projection less data has to be transferred. I want to transfer as little data from the database as possible, since it will be a bottle neck.

Comment: Does anybody know the answer to this? I'm still interested.